# bootstrap-datepicker throws jQuery not defined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, simple-form

I'm trying to use [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) on rails 4.2.
After following the instructions the datepicker doesn't work and I get the following error in the javascript console.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

**Line raising the error from bootstrap-datetimepicker.js**
The first line is where the reference error is thrown.

```
  // Neither AMD nor CommonJS used. Use global variables.
        if (!jQuery) {
            throw 'bootstrap-datetimepicker requires jQuery to be loaded first';
        }
        if (!moment) {
            throw 'bootstrap-datetimepicker requires Moment.js to be loaded first';
        }
```

**Application.js file**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require_tree .


$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').data({behaviour: "datepicker"}).datepicker();
});
```

Any ideas what's causing this? It looks like jQuery isn't loading even though it's placed above bootstrap-datetimepicker.js

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should have worked, take a look here:
https://github.com/TrevorS/bs3dp-test/

Are you able to run this app successfully? If not, it could be an issue with the gem. The only difference I see between your application.js and https://github.com/TrevorS/bs3dp-test/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/application.js is that they have moment required before bootstrap-sprockets